# XML schema validation - validating attribute values on same parameter names

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to perform a xml schema validation. Here is the excerpt of my xml file.

.....

```
<parameter name="ip">true</parameter>
<parameter name="address">calo</parameter>
<parameter name="telephone" locked="false">optional</parameter>
<parameter name="tools">cutter</parameter>
```

.......

When I generate the xsd file it looks as this.

```
  <xs:complexType name="parameterType" mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="propertyType" name="property" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="locked" use="optional"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="listenerType" mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="propertyType" name="property" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="class" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="locked" use="optional"/>
  </xs:complexType>
```

My problem is I want to validate each tags attribute value by imposing a restriction. (for 'ip' check the value (true) contains some character like '$' , for address value 'calo' contains the same character($).

I have used something like this but it only validates name of the attribute. (eg: ip - ok , i$p - error)

```
 <xs:attribute name="name" use="optional">
        <xs:simpleType>
           <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
           <xs:pattern value="[^$]*"/>
         </xs:restriction>
       </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:attribute>
```

What I want is to validate the value not the name of the attribute. (not the name 'address' but the value - 'calo' contains '$' ) Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot as long as `parameterType` contains sub-elements (`propertyType` in your case).

If `parameterType` did not contain any sub-element you can declare a restriction for its content like this:

```
<xs:simpleType name="propertyString">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="[^$]*"/>    
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:complexType name="propertyType">
  <xs:simpleContent>
    <xs:extension base="propertyString">
      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name" use="optional"/>
      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="locked" use="optional"/>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Note though that it is not possible to have different restrictions depending on the VALUE of one of the attributes.